# Controlling Font size in a beamer template

Tags: beamer

I am trying to use the online available beamer template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/imsaloquium-presentation-template/xrcchnsnkrxr

The template is very clean. Now at the left side of the end, I want to include my name. I have tried `textpos` package to include my name. But then the name size becomes very large.

[image]

I have tried

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{utopia} %font utopia imported
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usetheme{imsa}
\usecolortheme{imsa}
\newcommand\FrameText[1]{%
  \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(9pt,0.98\textheight)
    \raggedright #1\hspace{.0em}
  \end{textblock*}}
%------------------------------------------------------------
%This block of code defines the information to appear in the

%------------------------------------------------------------
% Patch to move title block down
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname beamer@@tmpl@title page\endcsname% <cmd>
  {\vfill}% <search>
  {\vspace*{0.8in}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother


%------------------------------------------------------------
%The next block of commands puts the table of 


\begin{document}



\begin{frame}{Test}
\small{
\FrameText{Tanmoy}
    }
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Is there any method to control it?

Comment: Note that sam's answer (below) uses the `lualatex` compiler. I was going to suggest it, but sam provided a good response. Also not that you do not need to provide `inputenc` since it is always utf-8 with lualatex.

Comment: @Tanmoy: you might want to get in contact with the author of your theme: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}` is not a good combination.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a footline:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage{utopia} %font utopia imported
\usetheme{imsa}
\usecolortheme{imsa}

\author{Tanmoy}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=black,bg=}
\setbeamerfont{author in head/foot}{size=\tiny}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
      \hfill%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works. But there is one problem. If I use a background in the frame, this excludes the footer, where my name is printed. Can you say how to extend the background image in the foot section also?

Comment: @TanmoyPati See my edited answer. You can set the background colour of the footline to be empty.